# regex extraction error

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract clients emails from forms of my website. To automate it I wrote

```
# filename variables
import re
import os
import urllib2
newfilename = 'result.txt'

id = 1
while (id < 25):
    html = urllib2.urlopen("https://mywebsite.com/printform.php?userid={id}".format(id=id)).read()
    bulkemail = re.findall(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)',html)
    id = id+1
emails = ""
for x in bulkemail:
    emails += str(x)+"\n"

# function to write file
def writefile():
        f = open(newfilename, 'w')
        f.write(emails)
        f.close()
        print ("File written.")
writefile()
```

This just prints out the last email in my file output . I know its kind of silly but can anyone point out where I am missing

Comment: What is the contents? Also, why use `.+` inside the pattern?

Comment: I see, you need to escape the `.` in your pattern where you have `.+`. I think you need to google for a better email address or use some kind of `r'\b\w[^\s@]*@\S*\b'` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `emails` declaration before the `while` loop and the `for` loop inside:

```
id = 1
emails = ""
while (id < 25):
    html = urllib2.urlopen("https://mywebsite.com/printform.php?userid={id}".format(id=id)).read()
    bulkemail = re.findall(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)',html)
    id = id+1

    for x in bulkemail:
        emails += str(x)+"\n"
```

Or, *collect the emails in a list* and then write:

```
id = 1
emails = []
while (id < 25):
    html = urllib2.urlopen("https://mywebsite.com/printform.php?userid={id}".format(id=id)).read()
    emails += re.findall(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)',html)
    id += 1

with open(newfilename, 'w') as f:
    for email in emails:
        f.write(email)
print("File written.")
```